# app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp" isn't working in ToolBar

Tags: android, android-layout, toolbar

I'm trying to display an `ImageView` spanning the entire toolbar (I can't use background).  here's my ToolBar layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/appbar_height"
    android:background="@drawable/backgorund_toolbar_tranluscent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/material_grey_700"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/appbar_height">

        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
                app:layout_aspectRatio="178%"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@color/material_grey_700"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_primary_text_default_material_dark"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/details"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/title"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/uploader"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/app_primary_text_default_material_dark"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/duration"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:textColor="@color/app_primary_text_default_material_dark"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/details"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialProgressBar.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                    app:mpb_progressStyle="horizontal"
                    app:mpb_useIntrinsicPadding="false"
                    android:indeterminate="false"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

As you can see I have added

```
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
```

as suggested by answers to many similer questions. I'm still getting an inset on the left side.

I'm using the following code in setting up ActionBar:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }
```

FYI, `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)`removes the inset and along with it the navigation up icon, which is not acceptable. Any way I can fix it other than adding my own custom up icon?

FYI2, `@style/ToolBarStyle` just inherits from `Theme.AppCompat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contentInset`s work right, but an offset appears if you want to show **up button** and `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` to `true`. As I understand, insets define *additional paddings*, not start position of `Toolbar`'s content.

#### Workaround:

What about redesign so that `AppBarLayout` contains your custom background, `Toolbar` (with transparent background) retains your complex title and insert `ProgressBar` wherever you want.

Something like this:

```
<AppBarLayout
    android:background="@color/material_grey_700">

    <!-- Just a Toolbar wrapper -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <!-- Background of Toolbar -->
       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/thumbnail"/>

       <Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:background="@android:color/transparent">

           <!-- Your multiline title stuff stays here. -->

       </Toolbar>

    </FrameLayout>

</AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: It fixes the image but the text and progress bar alignment is wrong.

Comment: @Binoy add a picture to show what you want to achieve. I'll try to help tomorrow :)